# problems with shadows glitching in Raytrace animation renders

Tags: animation, shadows

id be appreciative of some help with this issue. I am rendering out a simple building walkthrough and all of my shadows keep glitching and changing direction. Ive attached an example. I am rendering internally with raytracing.
many thanks
[image: example of problem]

Comment: It's too short to see it clearly.

Comment: sorry this is the max file I can upload. if you look at the the shadows created by the furniture

Comment: can you add some more information about the render/shadow settings? I assume Blender Internal renderer not cycles?

Comment: yes, internal blender render. Low samples on all of the lights (between 2 and 5)